# Why does an item disappear from my inventory when I press Q?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was fighting a zombie in a cave. I accidentally pressed <kbd>Q</kbd> and my diamond sword disappeared. When I switched to another diamond sword to test it also disappeared when I pressed <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 8):

The <kbd>Q</kbd> key is bound to `Drop Item` by default. The sword didn't 'disappear', it just fell on the floor. You can pick it back up by standing near the dropped item, but it **will** disappear if you don't pick it up within 5 minutes (6000 game ticks).